# Can't use https setup in Internet Information Services V 8.5

Tags: .net, http, ssl, iis, https

I configure the web .net with IIS, the web setup is successful with http, but when I binding with https the web doesn't work.

> 404 - File or directory not found.

[image]

Setup Success
[[image]]

IIS site Binding
[image: IIS Set Binding]

http:  port 80
https: port 443
Server : Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS Version 8.5

I have purchased an SSL certificate, and have installed it on my IIS,

is there a reason for setting my windows server?

Comment: It is very bad habit to capture error page without URLs. In your case, very likely that you used a wrong URL. A simple report can show you more, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi updated for capture error

Comment: Then the cause is clear. The HTTPS site binding you set is for `sub.xxx.com`, so that site won't handle requests on `www.xxx.com`. IIS then forwards the requests to another HTTPS binding under another site, which gives you 404.

Comment: sorry @Lex Li,,   wrong upload binding,    updated for binding,,    actually, http can be access from the client,   and https only server side can access as secure,,

Comment: Then you have two things to resolve in advance. 1) Check the certificate error and see what causes that 2) Use FRT to analyze the 404 and see what's the cause, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @ada If you get more related error messages by Lex Li's comment, please let me know.

Comment: Hi all,, 1) I try for https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html i get Certificate verified,   but the green line I found "This is not an ECCC certificate, so *_ECDSA_* cipher suites cannot be used". 
.

Comment: @LexLi      FYI I bought a domain and hosting on my server.

Comment: If Jexus Manager reports the certificate looks good, but Internet Explorer shows "Certificate error", I can only guess that your DNS setting for the domain is incorrect, so that HTTPS requests land on another place, which triggers the error. Not easy to troubleshoot further with accessing this machine. See if you have a friend that knows computer networking well, so that he/she can take a look.

Comment: hi all,,  @LexLi  my website already secure when I edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
.
and add IP my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must open port at hosting,

i.e 443

1. Open Port for 443 (Computer)  i.e 192.168.0.111
2. Open Port for 443 (Hosting Server point) i.e 192.168.0.1